# Maven project build into jar and war

Tags: jar, maven-3, war

I have a project with the following *pom.xml* and I have removed some of the unwanted stuff from it. What I intended to happen was to generate a jar file and ultimately generate a `war` package that includes the `jar` file as a library. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be happening with the following `pom.xml`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.test.abcd</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Test Application</name>

    ....

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>target/www/</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-war-in-classes</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</project>
```

Even though this generates both a `jar` and a `war` during the package phase, the `war` doesn't include `jar` file (`WEB-INF/lib/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`) as a library and in stead I see the following classes,

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
....
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/classes/
....
```

What could be causing this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a conf flag in war plugin configuration:

```
        <configuration>
          <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
        </configuration>
```

Quote from [https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html%20war%20plugin)

> How do I create a JAR containing the classes in my webapp?
>
> If you would simply like to package the classes and resources as a JAR in WEB-INF/lib rather than as loose files under WEB-INF/classes,
>   use the following configuration:
>
> ```
>           <plugin>
>             <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>3.1.0</version>
>             <configuration>
>               <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
>             </configuration>
>           </plugin>
> ```

Comment: Ive seen this flag ... Unfortunately, it will not do me any good if I ever want to obfuscate the jar file with proguard or something. Is there any other way you know ?

Comment: I see 2 other possible strategies : (1) Do as I suggest above, but only create the exploded war (i.e. no archive); then in a later stage, run the obfuscation plugin on the maven-war-plugin output (WEB-INF/lib folder).
(2) Don't do as I suggest above; build the jar, obfuscate it, and then configure maven-war-plugin to include custom jar files (or additional web resources that) include your obfuscated jar, and only after this, run some plugin that archives your exploded jar.
If you go with (2) I can edit my answer to provide an example.

Comment: (2) would definitely help and exactly what I was after .. would be good if you have something for that. With (1) as you suggested I could run maven-war-plugin twice I suppose but is that best practice ?

Comment: Well, (2) is indeed slightly better; but (1) doesn't necessarily mean that you need to run maven-war-plugin twice. You could use some zip plugin for that (that only knows to archive a folder). Or maven assembly plugin.
I can show an example for (2) but in several hours.

Comment: ...a quick search on SO says that you easily include a static resource in war plugin like this (i.e. treat your jar like you would treat a JS file, and include it as a static resource).

`<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> 
        <configuration> 
          <webResources> 
            <resource> 
              <directory>C:\\JAR</directory> 
              <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath> 
            </resource> 
          </webResources> 
        </configuration> `
So basically this would be the only extra step in your build.

Comment: Think I found something better: There is a maven proguard plugin that knows how to attach extra artifacts. Just set the `attach` flag to true in proguard config; and configure maven-war-plugin to exclude the original artifact (or classes folder, as you wish). This is so you don't end up with 2 jars in your war : one obfuscated, and one not.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. Il give it ago on your suggestions and report back on a solution to help others. Cheers man.