# Maven: change WAR structure

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project that I'm exporting as a WAR file. The WAR structure looks like this:

```
Project_Name.war
            |
            |__ META_INF
            |
            |__ WEB_INF_
                        |
                        |__ lib
                        |
                        |__ classes_
                                    |
                                    |__ project_package(project src code)
                                    |
                                    |__ META_INF
                                    |
                                    |__ WEB_INF_
                                    |           |
                                    |           |__ web.xml
                                    |__ project config files
```

As you can see, my project src code is coming inside the `classes` directory. Rather than this, I'd like to include my project src code as a JAR file inside my `lib` folder. Also the `web.xml` is coming inside the `classes` folder. I would like to put it outside the `classes` folder i.e., inside `WEB_INF` along with `lib` and 'classes'.

I can always do both these operations manually.

My expected WAR structure is something like this:

```
Project_Name.war
            |
            |__ META_INF
            |
            |__ WEB_INF_
                        |
                        |__ lib_
                        |       |__ Project.jar
                        |
                        |__ classes_
                        |           |
                        |__ web.xml |
                                    |__ project config files
```

But I was wondering whether this could be done through the projects' `pom.xml`? I would appreciate some help from the maven veterans out there. Thanks.

I'm using the `maven_war_plugin` and the `mvn install` command to build the WAR.

Including the pom.xml structure:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>PROJECT_A</groupId>
    <artifactId>PROJECT_A</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>config</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        .
        .
        .
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        .
        .
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Maybe you should include the POM as well as the command you are using to build.  It is strange to see source files in classes folder.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Command used to build war is `mvn clean install`. Give me a moment to include structure of pom

Comment: First why are you change the convention in Maven? What kind of problem are you trying to solve? Keep the convention over configuration paradigm...it makes your life easier...and the structure of your war file looks wrong...

Answer (score 0):

How do I create a JAR containing the classes in my webapp?

```
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#attached

You scan specify the web.xml location with the webXml attribute: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#webXml

Moreover I suggest to follow the https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html instead of WebContent.

Comment: Although this seems to be the right answer, but it looks like this answer is copied from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43972148/maven-project-build-into-jar-and-war). @Dennis Kieselhorst, people would really appreciate if you can cite their answers instead of copying it.

Comment: I have copied it from maven.apache.org, link is part of the answer.